# Can someone help, my player, (which is a cube in a 3d environment), it teleports to 0,0 and i cant move it at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(i think that it is in the update function of the code)

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 18;
    private Rigidbody rig;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 Movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rig.MovePosition(transform.position = Movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only include the tag for the language you're programming in. C# and UnityScript are two separate programming languages.

Comment: In addition to before comment: `UnityScript` is also deprecated and `c#` currently the only language supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have equals doing

```
void Update()
{
    float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.position = Movement;

    rig.MovePosition(transform.position);
}
```

Can you see now what the issue is?

- your `Movement` will every frame be quite small since it is multiplied by `Time.deltaTime` (for 60 F/s this equals about `1/60 = 0.017`) - *not part of the issue yet ;)*
- Then you set your object fix to this position via `transform.position`. This will always stay quite close around `0,0,0` with a range of about `1/60 * 18 = 0.3`.
- And finally you tell the `Rigidbody` to move to exact the same position in which your object is now already in anyway.

---

[`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) expects an absolute world position so what you rather want to do is using

```
rig.MovePosition(rig.position + Movement);
```

Then note also that any Physics related movement should rather be done in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) so your code should look like e.g.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 18;

    // You could/should reference this directly via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rig;

    private Vector3 _movement;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rig) rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Get User input in Update
    private void Update()
    {
        float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        _movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // But apply Physics in FixedUpdate
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rig.MovePosition(rig.position + _movement);
    }
}
```

---

Note that alternatively without separating both you could also directly assign the [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) instead:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 18;

    // You could/should reference this directly via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rig;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rig) rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        var movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        rig.velocity = movement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the object moves within the margin of error with respect to zero, but after the horizontal and vertical become equal to (0, 0), then the location becomes equal to the zero coordinate.

Read this page, I think you can find the answer to your question in it.
[`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

Possible Solution:

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 Movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        //Replacing '=' with '+' or '-' should help
        rig.MovePosition(transform.position + Movement);
    }
```

Comment: In general do not move `Rigidbody` in the `Update` method! Physics related movements should only be done in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate.html)

Comment: In fact, both options will work correctly, but it is preferable, of course, to `FixedUpdate`. If you are using `FixedUpdate`, you should also use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead of `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: No it is also recommended to use `Time.deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate` .. see API to `Time.fixedDelatTime`

Comment: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Comment: Yes and from four own link: `For reading the delta time it is recommended to use Time.deltaTime instead because it automatically returns the right delta time if you are inside a FixedUpdate function or Update function.`

Comment: [Time-fixedDeltaTime API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) Yes, you are right, it is better to use `deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`. But both options are correct.